# How to loop through xml elements using xsl

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

I have a scenario like this in xml:

```
<ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name="Planing Status" />
  <FieldRef Name="Resource Status" />
  <FieldRef Name="Development Status" />
  <FieldRef Name="Testing Status" />
</ViewStatus>
```

I have to loop through this in xsl, I followed below:

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_body.Status" match="FieldRef[@Name=/ViewFields/FieldRef[1]]" mode="body">
```

IT'S NOT RETURNING ANY THING
@Name variable i am using several places in this section. I want to assign FieldRef values to @Name variable through loop.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of two of the problems in your code and for providing a clear solution.

Comment: Well in your posted XML sample all `FieldRef` elements are empty so `@Name=/ViewFields/FieldRef[1]` does not select anything as no `Name` attribute is empty as well. Otherwise I can't help as your question is not very clear. You might want to post a sample of the result you want to generate with XSLT for the input sample you posted, then we can suggest appropriate XSLT code. With XSLT/XPath `@Name` is not a selecting a variable, rather it selects an attribute of the name `Name`.

Comment: Dimitre was pretty ambitious in giving you a solution that involved guessing what your problem is. He was also very generous in giving you +1 for the question. As for me, I can see why your code doesn't do anything, but you haven't said clearly what you want it to do, so I cant' tell you how to correct it.

Comment: How can i loop through to get the FieldRef Name values in XSL..!

Comment: Please visit this url for clear post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891949/loop-through-xml-elements-in-xsl

Comment: My scenario is to apply for multiple columns. I just found one of the related article, please follow the url you will understand

http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html#comment-10781

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_body.Status" 
     match="FieldRef[@Name=/ViewFields/FieldRef[1]]" mode="body">
```

**There are two things to note here**:

1. **The match attribute contains an XPath expression that, when applied on the provided XML document, selects *no* node at all**. It is supposed to select an element named `FieldRef` the string value of whose `Name` attribute is equal to the string value of the first `FieldRef` child of the `ViewFields` top element. However, none of the `FieldRef` elements in the XML document have any (non-empty) string value. On the other side, the string values of all `Name` attributes are non-empty. My guess is that you wanted: `match="FieldRef[@Name=/ViewFields/FieldRef[1]/@Name]"`
2. **Any template in a (non-anonymous) mode isn't considered by the XSLT processor for selection if its mode is different from the current mode**.

As the initial mode in XSLT 1.0 (and in XSLT 2.0) is the empty (anonymous) mode, the only way to make a template in a non-anonymous mode considered for selection is to explicitly specify the mode on an `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*" mode="body"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name=/ViewFields/FieldRef[1]/@Name]"
               mode="body">
  <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces this result, showing that the template is selected for processing**:

```
Planing Status
```

Comment: Thank you and appreciate your quick reply, let me give it a try.

Comment: Hi Dimitre
I have tried your suggestion, it's not working out. Let me explain the problem in detail.

I am trying to LOOP through the XML for Status(Name Attribute of xml) for each record and show a different image for each status.  This should happen for all the four named columns in the xml.

I think I have to use for-each to loop through the xml, for all the records for all the columns. Can you please let me know how to solve this.

SharePoint list has these columns. Please see the following post for rest of the issue.

Comment: <ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name="PStatus" />
  <FieldRef Name="RStatus" />
  <FieldRef Name="DStatus" />
</ViewStatus>

Comment: I have the following XSL code
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_body.Status" match="FieldRef[@Name=/ViewFields/FieldRef[1]/@Name]" mode="body">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'Completed'">
                    <img src="IMNON.png" alt="Status: {$thisNode/@Status}"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <img src="IMNBUSY.png" alt="Status: {$thisNode/@Status}"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: @user547077: Please, edit your question with clear and *legible* description of the problem. Bear in mind next time you are going to ask a question, to specify it in a very clear and proper way. Show: 1) The exact XML document. 2) What the processing must return -- the exact and complete result. 3) What are the rules/constraints for the transformation.

Comment: Hi Dimitre
Some reason im not able to format the text here, i reposted the question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891949/loop-through-xml-elements-in-xsl

Can you please have find that.
Thank you