# Loop through XML elements in XSL

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

I have in XML file like this

```
<ViewFields> 
<FieldRef Name="Approval Status" /> 
<FieldRef Name="Requirement Status" /> 
<FieldRef Name="Development Status" /> 
<FieldRef Name="Testing Status" />
</ViewStatus>
```

I have the following XSL code to get FieldRef values.

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_body.Status" match="FieldRef[@Name='ViewFields/FieldRef[1]/@Name']" mode="body">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'Completed'">
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNON.png" alt="Status: {$thisNode/@Status}"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'In Progress'">
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNIDLE.png" alt="Status: {$thisNode/@Status}"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNBUSY.png" alt="Status: {$thisNode/@Status}"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

I am trying to LOOP through FieldRef**[x]** to get the values one by one, it's not returning anything.  I want to assign FieldRef values to @Name variable through loop.

Comment: Seems obvious to me: See my answer. Note: From the definition of the problem I still don't see what task are you solving -- you *must* provide *real* XML document and most importantly, the exact wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

**This is obvious**:

1. `match="FieldRef[@Name='ViewFields/FieldRef[1]/@Name']"`. No `Name` attribute has as string value the string `'ViewFields/FieldRef[1]/@Name'`. You most probably want an XPath expression here, not a string. Use `match="FieldRef[@Name=ViewFields/FieldRef[1]/@Name]"`
2. There is no `Name` attribute in the provided XML document with string value `"Completed"` or with string value `"In Progress"`.
3. Also, there isn't any `Status` attribute at all in the XML document.

Comment: Hi Dimitre
Please find the below link. This is the scenario i am exactly working.In this post it's working fine for single Status column, I want to apply if List has multiple Status columns.

http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html#comment-10781

Please go through above url you will clearly understand. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @user547077: Why do you think the blog post would make things clear? Definitely not. It seems to me that you don't know what is the exact problem -- since you cannot describe it.

Comment: Dimitre, I posted the exact output requirement in this below link, as the current thread is not accepting formatted text. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893396/loop-through-xml-elements-in-xsl

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have all of the context needed to answer correctly, but you should consider simplifying your construct down to a "for-each" for your looping.

given xml

```
<ViewFields> 
<FieldRef Name="Approval Status" />
<FieldRef Name="Requirement Status" /> 
<FieldRef Name="Development Status" /> 
<FieldRef Name="Testing Status" />
</ViewFields>
```

with xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template name="main" match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/ViewFields/FieldRef">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Name = 'Approval Status'">
                <ApprovalStatus/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@Name = 'Requirement Status'">
                <RequirementStatus/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <SomethingElse/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This might be a bit closer to what you were wanting.

Comment: Jonfen,
Thank you for reply, Here the scenario i am working. The same i have to apply for multiple Columns. please visit this link
http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html#comment-10781

Thank you